# How can I switchMap 2 Observable function in synchronous fashion but get the first observable value to continue?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I have this operation for an effect/ngrx side effect:

```
    @Effect() newMessages$ = Observable.interval(5000)
        .withLatestFrom(this.store.select<UiState>("uiState"))
        .map(([any,uiState]) => uiState)
        .filter(uiState => Boolean(uiState.userId))
        .switchMap(uiState => this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId)
         **//--How to run below function, which also return an Observable for only indicate success and error.But I need to pass on the Observable from above to continue** 
         this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(uiState.userId)
        )
        .withLatestFrom(this.store.select<UiState>("uiState"))
        .map(([unreadMessages, uiState]) => new NewMessagesReceivedAction({
          unreadMessages,
          currentThreadId: uiState.currentThreadId,
          currentUserId: uiState.userId
        }))
```

My goal is AFTER uiState => this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId) which will return me an Observable from a Firebase, angularFire2 LIST operator, I need to run an other Firebase option to delete those messages I already received from Firebase. Then I pass those Observable to NewMessagesReceivedAction.

this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(uiState.userId) is like a side effect inside a side effect. I need to messages from Firebase, but I also need to remove them from Firebae after I get them. And everything needs to chain in the  @Effect()... Which RXJS operator I need to get this job done?

UPDATE: Here is my loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId) service all:

```
    loadNewMessagesForUser(uid: string): Observable<Message[]> {
        return this.findMessagesForMessageKeys(this.findMessageKeysPreUserUnread(uid));
      }

    findMessageKeysPreUserUnread(uid: string):Observable<string[]> {
      return this.db.list('MessagesQueuePerUser/' + uid)
  .map(getKeys => getKeys.map(p => p.$key));
     }

    findMessagesForMessageKeys(messageKeys$:Observable<string[]>): Observable<Message[]> {
    return messageKeys$
     .map(pspp => pspp.map(messageKey => this.db.object('message/' + messageKey)))
     .flatMap(fbojs => Observable.combineLatest(fbojs))
   }
```

It is a standard AngularFire2 code that return an observable. How would I build my above service-methods in a way that they return one single data-emission per method-call? How would I write differently to make it more solid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
.switchMap(uiState => this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId)
    .switchMap(data => this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(uiState.userId).mapTo(data))
)
```

---

If I understood your comment correctly and `loadNewMessagesForUser` has multiple emissions (which is not an optimal case to start with), you could do the following:

```
.switchMap(uiState => this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId)
    .toArray()
    .switchMap(data => this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(uiState.userId).switchMapTo(Observable.from(data)))
)
```

But I strongly suggest that you build your service-methods in a way that they return one single data-emission per method-call (unless the data is emitted over time and may not exist at the time of the method-call)

Comment: This gives me some very strange response. Lets say loadNewMessagesForUser response 4 new messages (4 Firebase lists). But then I can see the list going down to only 1 (if I add .do(console.log) ), and the final response of my NewMessagesReceivedAction only contain ONE unreadMessages in the array. But it should be 4 unreadMessages.

Comment: Oh, so `loadNewMessagesForUser` basically has 4 data-emissions?

Comment: It load all the new messages that user have not read yet. It is a Firebase list. But your code only get the last one for some reason. I think it is b/c of  observable - b/c the code deleting them as well. What I want is to get all of them and then get rid of it in Firebase. Kinda like a notification bust...

Comment: What if I do .first() instead of .toArray()? So I will get the first emissions of loadNewMessagesForUser and then complete that observable. To your suggestion, If I build service-methods only emit once, what is the point to use observable pattern? Is the benefit of observable is to listen to the stream of data and update it as data coming in? I use Firebase. So whenever data change in Firebase, it reflect in the front-end via web socket.

Comment: I added Update. Could you give me an example of one single data-emission per method-call of my above update (code to list Firebase basically)

Comment: If you have socket-updates over time, that is totally fine, but then it probably would make sense to have the @Effect run according to on update from firebase (and maybe use `.bufferTime` if it should not be done more often than once every 5 seconds but not use a hardcoded interval

Comment: But to your suggestions, that is correct: `first` or `take(1)` would probably we better if you don't need ALL the values and the delete-call can be done with just one value.

Comment: olsn, the problem is, I do not know how to listen to Firebase update with @Effect. Should I open another ticket maybe you can give me some advices  there? I would love to NOT use interval.

Comment: I open a new thread here regarding listen to firebase and trigger effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857248/how-to-listen-to-firebase-update-and-trigger-effect-store-side-effect-to-update